# Managing custom Screens in XNA 4.0

Tags: c#, oop, xna

I'm going through the process of building my OOP skills,
and have written an abstract Screen class with an update method that takes a KeyboardState and MouseState as parameters,  and a draw method that takes a SpriteBatch as a parameter.
The class also includes a bool isEnabled, along with methods to enable/disable it.

It's worked fine so far, extended these and used without a problem
until it comes to moving from one screen to another.
I want to know why the screen was disabled, and which to enable next.

At the moment I use an int variable within the Screen, and the main class checks if the class implementing Screen is disabled and has a "disabled reason" int.  If so, it does an action based on that int.
I guess that an int isn't the best choice and an Enum would be better?

But my real question is, is there a better way of relaying data back to the main class?
Would I have to poll each disabled class to see if there's a "reason for being disabled code"?

Answer (score 1):

I will only answer the following question:

> ```
> I guess that an int isn't the best choice and an Enum would be better?
> ```

Even if you use a enumation you would still be using an integer value since an enumeration has a integer value associated with it.

the only benefit of an enumeration would be you would have a textual represenation of the reason instead of ( 0, 1, 2,3 .. ).

Comment: Thanks for your answer :)

Yeah, my thinking was just that it's bad practice to give meaning to plain interger values in my code.  Not to mention confusing when I come to extend it later.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess that an int isn't the best choice and an Enum would be better?

Correct. Make an enum, for example:

```
enum DisabledReason { Something, SomethingElse; }
```

> is there a better way of relaying data back to the main class? Would I have to poll each disabled class to see if there's a "reason for being disabled code"?

**Give the base screen class an event** - something like this ([MSDN for EventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx)):

```
public event EventHandler<DisabledReason> Disabled;
```

Make the main class attach an event handler to the screens as it creates them.

Make the screen class call the `Disabled` event handler when it becomes disabled.

The upshot will be that the main class is informed *why* a screen becomes disabled, *when* it becomes disabled. You pass the `this` of the screen to the `Disabled` event as the source parameter - so the main class will know which screen the event is coming from.

(Note: this is very much a crash course on using events - do a bit more research on how to use events, if you need to.)

Comment: I haven't come across writing events at all.
It certainly seems more efficient than constant polling. You've given me my next area to study :P

Thanks for your answer :D

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest "borrowing" from the [Game State Management](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management) sample on the Microsoft App Hub site. It's all about screen management.  (Be sure to download the sample for Windows - unless your making a phone app).

> The ScreenManager class is a reusable
>   component that maintains a stack of
>   one or more GameScreen instances. It
>   coordinates the transitions from one
>   screen to another, and takes care of
>   routing user input to whichever screen
>   is on top of the stack.

Comment: I considered looking for something like that, but decided to attempt figuring out my own way as a learning exercise, to become more familiar / comfortable with OOP programming.
Thanks for the link though, I'll have a look at how it works after I've gone as far as I can push myself :)

Answer (score 1):

Even if you do end up "borrowing" code to figure out the solution, you can still get some good OOP principles out of it.  EventHandlers are a classic example of the "observer" pattern.